# Exclude Current user email and send notification

Tags: users, email, notifications

I am currently building a wordpress plugin to send email notification to list of users roles who comments on a post.

**For Example:**

If a user with "subscriber" role comments on a post all the other users who have "subscriber" role gets email alert.Currently i have achieved this through the following code

```
if( current_user_can('subscriber'))
{
$user_query = new WP_User_Query( array( 'role' => 'subscriber');
                foreach ( $user_query->results as $user ) 
                {
                    $mail=$user->user_email;


                    $subject  ="this is example";
                    $message  = "";
                    $message .= "$post_permalink\n";

                    wp_mail($user->user_email,  $subject,$message);         
}
}
```

The above code sends email to all the users who have "subscriber" role.

**Output:**

It gets even the current user who comments on the post and send the email notification.

**Problem to be solved:**

How can i exclude the current user email and send only notification  to other users  those who have "subscriber" role .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should know that [`current_user_can()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/current_user_can) only accepts capabilities, not roles, so you are using it wrong and you can end up with unexpected results.

That being said, to exlude users form `WP_User_Query` you can use the [exclude parameter](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_User_Query#Include_.26_Exclude_Parameters):

```
// Get current user data
$user = wp_get_current_user();

// Check if current user is a subscriber
if( ! empty( $user ) && in_array( "subscriber", (array) $user->roles ) ) {

    $user_query = new WP_User_Query( array(
                                           'role'   => 'subscriber',
                                           // exlude current user
                                           'exclude' => array( $user->ID ),
                                     )
    );

    $subscribers = $user_query->get_results();

    if( ! empty( $subscribers ) ) {
        foreach ( $subscribers as $user )  {

            $mail = $user->user_email;
            $subject  ="this is example";
            $message  = "";
            $message .= "$post_permalink\n";

            wp_mail( $mail, $subject, $message);

        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Following should works for you:-

```
 if( current_user_can('read')) { 
    $exclude_user = array();
    $exclude_user[] =get_current_user_id();
    $args = array(
    'role' => 'subscriber',
    'exclude' => $exclude_user
    );
    $user_query = new WP_User_Query( $args); 
    foreach ( $user_query->results as $user ) { $mail=$user->user_email;

                    $subject  ="this is example";
                    $message  = "";
                    $message .= "$post_permalink\n";

                    wp_mail($user->user_email,  $subject,$message);         
    }


}
```

Comment: Using `current_user_can()` function to check roles is an old practice not recommended any more (at least since 3 years ago). In fact, the recomendation talks only abour capabilities. [If you use `current_user_can()` with roles, you can end up with unexpected results](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/22624).

Comment: Wisdmlabs the above code is not working for me

Comment: cybmeta I dont have problem in checking the user role i have problem in fetching the values of user with "subscriber" role. It get current user email  also.. i need to avoid fetching it..

Comment: I didn't say you have a problem with that, I said that you can end up with problems because you are using `current_user_can` incorrectly. That comment was not intended to answer your question but provide an advise.

Comment: We have just given the approach for fetching users with role as subscriber excluding current user id.

Comment: Thankyou Cybmeta the above code posted by you works fine

Comment: @pradeepkumar1565 Please, comment on my answer instead of this one and please, if my answer fixs your problem, mark the answer as accepted so other users can find the correct answer quickly. Your comment on this answer talking about the code on another answer can confuse users.